# Emacs... as your default shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, emacs

Is it possible instead of loading /bin/bash, for my terminal to load emacs or emacsclient when I open it up, with a session for eshell? And is it feasible to ssh->screen from an emacs session without running into problems?

I want to do this purely to learn about emacs being as I like it so much.

No hate text, etc please :)

Answer (score 7):

```
emacs -f eshell
```

EDIT:
If you don't want to start a new emacs you can use emacsclient.

```
emacsclient -e '(eshell)'
```

Make sure you have started the server the best way to do it is to add 
`(server-start)` in your . emacs

Comment: That spawns a separate instance of Emacs. It would be nice to do this using `--batch` (similar to the way dunnet is invoked) but I can't seem to do it.

Comment: Aside from NTEmacs (where it's not available) `emacs --daemon` is surely the preferable way to start the server (supported in 23.1+). Even better, `emacsclient --alternate-editor=""` starts emacs in daemon mode and connects to it, if no server was running, so you can simply use that as your standard emacs command.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your shell to `/usr/bin/emacs` (or wherever it is) to make it your default shell. It will probably act weird though since Emacs is not a shell. It's an editor. Programs expect your shell to behave in a certain fashion and Emacs won't work that way.

You can do an <kbd>M-x</kbd>`term`<kbd>ret</kbd> to get a terminal from which you can connect to a remote machine and start a screen. I don't know about the quality of the emulation though. No harm trying.

Neither of these look useful to me and the former is definitely a trouble maker.

Comment: I generally meant eshell and not really /usr/bin/emacs -- thanks

Comment: "It's an editor." - Emacs is, and I'm sure any hardcore user of it will agree ... whatever we want it to be.

Comment: Point taken amphetamachine. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.  I did for a few months once.  A few things act funny most can be tamed.  It was a great laugh to see coworkers react when they saw me log in to emacs.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo /usr/bin/emacs >> /etc/shells

chsh -s /usr/bin/emacs
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried running screen from within Emacs (in a shell buffer), but I get the following:

```
angelv@vaso:~$ screen -D -R
Clear screen capability required.
angelv@vaso:~$
```

so I guess that's not possible. In any case, I don't see why you'd want this (and I use daily screen + emacs).

Comment: It actually works from eshell!!! I have created a screen in eshell and attached to ir from bash. Works fine!